# How to define different sets of variables for a JMeter Test Plan

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I'm trying to understand how to best structure a simple login/logout load test in JMeter. My basic test is structures as follows:

```
- Test Plan
  - Thread Group 1
    - Http Request Defaults
    - Http Cookie Manager
    - CSV Data Set Config
    - Login Controller
      - Login Request (username/password)
      - 2FA Request
        - Request Assertion
    - Logout Controller
      - Logout Request
        - Request Assertion
    - View Results Tree
```

I have a list of 1000 users in my CSV.  I would like to structure this test so I can run simulataneous tests against 4 different servers in my cluster.  Each server should be handling 10 threads.

I figure the Thread Group should be defined as 10 threads.  But then how do I launch 4 Groups in parallel (each directed to a different server)?  Do I have to replicate the Thread Group 4 times?  That doesn't seem logical.

Additionally, I have multiple environments that I want to test against.  Each environment has different servers.  I was hoping to define groups of variables, but not sure how to do this, and then just specify the environment I want to run again.

Ex:

```
 prod : 
   server:
     - 10.1.1.1
     - 10.1.1.2
     - 10.1.1.3
     - 10.1.1.4
   protocol: https
   contextRoot: /

 dev:
   server:
     - 192.168.1.1
     - 192.168.1.2
   protocol: http
   contextRoot: /test/
```

And then in the TestPlan simply specify the environment and determine the correct number of ThreadGroups to spawn (1 group per server), and use the correct endpoints, protocols, etc as defined.  But I can't seem to find how to structure nested data sets and or how to dynamically create Thread Groups from it.  Is this not feasible?

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, you do not need to use 4 Thread Groups or parallel scripts. This can be achieved using Java code in JSR223 Sampler.

Depending upon the Threads requirement of 10 Threads on each server, use something like this. I am processing based on `${__threadNum}` function. First 10 Threads will go to IP1, next to IP2 and so on.... Using these kind of logic any complex scenario can be achieved for Cluster and Hosts. Excuse for my Java Code [I am not that good in Java], I know more efficient code can be written, which I will learn.

```
String currentThread = ${__threadNum};
String IP1 = "10.0.0.1";
String IP2 = "10.0.0.2";
String IP3 = "10.0.0.3";
String IP4 = "10.0.0.4";
//log.info("Parameter ThreadNumber: " + currentThread);
int tNum = Integer.parseInt(currentThread);

       if (tNum <= 10)
        {
            vars.put("host",IP1);
        }
        else if(tNum > 10 && tNum <= 20)
        {
            vars.put("host",IP2);
        }
        else if (tNum > 20 && tNum <= 30)
        {
            vars.put("host",IP3);
        }
        else if (tNum > 30 && tNum <= 40)
        {
            vars.put("host",IP4);
        }
        else
        {
            vars.put("host",IP1);
        }

log.info("Parameter ThreadNumber: " + currentThread);
log.info("Parameter Host: " + vars.get("host"));
```

Now, in HTTP sampler, use :

```
${host} in Server Name or IP field. If Port and Protocol needs to be changed, change that in Java code
```

[image]

Coming to CSV file, I am assuming it contains Username and Password for login. Various settings can be done as per your requirement. I will suggest to generate that Username and Password on the fly.

Note : ThreadGroup settings need to be done depending upon your Requirement. 40 Number of Threads, Rampup = 1 and Loop Count.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) and [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) as this is how you can avoid code duplication and violating [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

So you can move common logic into a Test Fragment and reference it from multiple places [providing different parameters](https://dzone.com/articles/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide) basing on your test scenario.